# Is it possible to fire Java methods from Jena SWRL Rules

Tags: jena, swrl

I am working on a Performance analysis on Ontology based Context Management and Process based Context Management.
However, in order to create a similar scenario with the PCM case study, I am required to fire Java methods directly from Jena SWRL Rules during reasoning. I have made a lot of research to no avail but my professor claims it is possible with Jena.
For Example,

```
Forward(vpnAccess)<--hasChain(vpnAccess,Forward)^
                     hasExternalInterface(vpnAccess,eth1)^
                     hasSrcIP(vpnAccess,ip4.3.2.1)^
                     hasDstIP(vpnAccess,ip1.2.3.4)^
                     hasProtocol(vpnAccess,tcp)^
                     hasDstPort(vpnAccess,portVPN)^
                     hasTarget(vpnAccess,acceept)

 Where Forward is a java class method:
    public static void Forward(String eth1,String Chain,Ip SrcIpAddr,Ip DestIpAddr,.. )
                      {......
                         .......}
```

Comment: Could you point to this 'Jena SWRL Rules' implementation? I'm not aware of SWRL for jena.

Answer (score 0):

There is a brief tutorial on using "[Pellet + OWLAPI + SWRL Rules](http://themindwobbles.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/short-tutorial-on-using-pellet-owlapi-swrl-rules/)" you can read it.